# How do I push an object into an array nested in an object and retain reactivity in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following object:

```
{ property1:'value1', property2:'value2', property3:[{ property4:'value4' },{ property5: 'value5'}], property6:'value6' }
```

And now I want to push the following into the value of property3

```
{ property7:‘value7’}
```

The final result would be like

```
{ property1:'value1', property2:'value2', property3:[{ property4:'value4' },{ property5: 'value5'},{property7:'value7'}], property6:'value6'}
```

Any idea how to do this?

I tried `Object.assign`but that does not work in this case because of the array.

Comment: Why not just `obj.property3.push({ property7: 'value7'})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
obj.property3.push({ property7: 'value7'})
obj={...obj}
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Adding property to an object is straight forward. But when you make this multi level object reactivity may get loss. What I suggested is assigning new object to the variable with old value which forces it to rerender

Comment: @Shirish looking at the console log your suggestion adds the newly added data correctly into the object. But reactivity seems to be lost. there is no re-rendering.

Comment: There was an error in my code. I got it working now. Thanks!